# Cross-Compiling Qt6 for Zero 2 W?

Tags: cross-compilation, qt, pi-zero-w-2

I am trying to build a cross compiling setup for the following system configuration:

- Qt6.5 LTS
- Running Raspberry Pi OS Lite 64-bit based on Bookworm
- Host: Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS on WSL

There aren't many tutorials that are targeting this specific board. It is the closest to Raspberry Pi 3B(because of the core), but all the tutorials are built for 32-bit OS. There are tutorials for 64-bit versions, but only for Raspberry Pi 4, and it has direct support from Qt itself, with dedicated configuration in [qtbase](https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/mkspecs/devices/linux-rasp-pi4-aarch64): `mkspecs/devices/linux-rasp-pi4-aarch64`. I do not know what problems I'll run into as RPi 4 uses VideoCore VI, while Zero 2 W runs VideoCore IV. Currently, I'm trying to follow [this](https://wiki.qt.io/Cross-Compile_Qt_6_for_Raspberry_Pi), but it targets RPi 4.

Has anyone been able to do what I'm trying to? It seems weird how less Zero 2 W is talked about despite having such amazing hardware.